# How to get first string form file using powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm writing powershell script to get first string delimited by single space- ' '. I tried to use

```
Get-Content file.txt -TotalCount 1 | -split 1
```

but it didn't work. I also tried

```
Get-Content file.txt -TotalCount 1 -Delimiter ' '
```

This line didn't worked too. How to do it properely?

Comment: Can you add a sample of a file and what is your expected result?

Comment: Please add content example. Can not understand your 'delimited by single space'

Comment: The content of file looks like this: word1 word2 word3... The name of file is passed as parameter in for each loop, but I add to this string and fails. Foreach( $loop_param in $table_with_names)... $local_var_with_content=... First and second answer located below haven't work.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be what you want (can't tell for sure from the questions):

```
(Get-Content file.txt -TotalCount 1).split()[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

you are not far, try this :

```
(-split (gc C:\temp\test.bat -Totalcount 1) )[0]
```

Comment: I used $var=(-split (gc $loop_through_list_local_var + '.ext' -Totalcount 1) )[0]  and didn't worked.

Comment: this doesnt  make sense as we dont know what is $loop_.... , please update your question with the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to work out a loop but this line will get the very first string delimited by a space

((Get-Content file.txt)[0] -split " ")[0]

Comment: If the OP only wants the first line using `-Totalcount 1` is preferential since it will not being reading the whole file into memory.

Answer (score -1):

If you need to strictly split with spaces (single space character):

```
@($(@(Get-Content -TotalCount 1 -Path 'D:\___.txt'  )[0]).ToString().Split(@(' ')))
```

If you have 1+ spaces, tabs etc:

```
@($(@(Get-Content -TotalCount 1 -Path 'D:\___.txt'  )[0]).ToString() -split '\s+')
```